# PHP move_uploaded_file() error

Tags: php, file-upload

I know this is a bit blunt but the following has been my main focus for about 3 hours now and I need help.
I have checked file permissions (777). And, perhaps the most annoying part, it was working yesterday!!! The "if" statements are fine as I've checked it gets to `move_uploaded_file()` by echoing a statement. I was getting an error at some point but I think that's passed, The error was:

```
[Thu Dec 19 03:53:06 2013] [error] [client 46.208.50.146] File does not exist: /some_directory/[object File], referer: http://my_domain/
```

The code:

```
$rand_string = "";
$rand_file_string = "";
$characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $rand_string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $rand_file_string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
$fileNameMain = $rand_file_string . "-" . str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"]);
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"];
$pathAndName =  "../../../../../my_domain.com/htdocs/southwye/upload/" . $rand_file_string . "-" . $fileNameMain;
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"]);
$extension = strtolower(end($temp));
if ((($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
  if ($_FILES["input_mainpic"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    if (file_exists($rand_file_string . $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $rand_file_string . $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
      }
    }
  }
```

Please don't get the wrong idea...I have *actually* looked into this but have come up short! The file that the code is running from has 777 permissions. I have tried to use a different directory and give it the required permission but nothing happened.

I'm getting absolutely no feedback from PHP (from which I'd assume no errors in the code)

Comment: $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"];

Answer (score 2):

i think your referred temp file location is wrong

instead of

```
$fileTmpLoc = "/temp/" . $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"];
```

u have to use

```
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't change the code back after trying a different directory

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your upload file path folder unable to reach your folder path, I've rewritten as below,

By adding as manually
`"../../../../../my_domain.com/htdocs/southwye/upload/";` below mentioned code retrive the site path directly. It may be the reason file uploading error

```
    $filePath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $rootPath = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    $htmlPath = str_replace($root, '', $filePath);
    $fileNameMain = $rand_file_string . "-" . str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["name"]);
    $pathAndName =  $htmlPath."/upload/" . $rand_file_string . "-" . $fileNameMain;
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["input_mainpic"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: I have no idea what's doing what here; what directory is  "realpath(dirname(__FILE__));" retrieving?